Table with a 1 pixel height row in Blazor
I am not really a front-end designer, but had some code that is working on an small website.
When I am trying to use the same code/styling in Blazor, it does not really work.
My goal is that I have a pixel-line above (and under) the rows in a table.

I use an image that is 1 pixel in height, and in my normal website this makes that cell and row also 1 pixel in height. :
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr><td><img src="bar.gif" width="100%" height="1" alt=""></td></tr>

   ....

I seem not to get this working in Blazor.

I do not understand why.
I have tried some more style :
border-collapse: collapse;
<tr style="height:3px !important;">

margin="0" padding="0" (in TR / TD and in the IMG).
all does not help.
Anyone any idea why this is not working well ?

Blazor includes Bootstrap by default and that means you already have some styles for table, tr and td.
You could start out with a "Blazor Server App Empty" (dotnet <= 7) but there is no 'empty' version for Blazor 8's  Web App template.
The quick fix here is  <td style="line-height:1px"> around the img elements although I would prefer a css class over inline styling.

The quick fix worked, thanks. I will change to css class if that works also, but wanted to find the base of the problem.
